# How to reset a counter back to 0 with a button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a counter in javascript right now and a button that adds 1 value to the counter, this is what I have so far:

```js
    var counter = 0;
    var a = 0;
    var add = function(valueToAdd){
        a += valueToAdd;
        document.getElementById('Value').innerHTML = a;
  }
```

```html
    Value $<span id="Value">0</span> 
    <button width="500" height="500" id = add class="button button1" onclick="javascript:add(1)">Add Value</button>
```

I need a button to reset the counter back to 0 any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Add a button,  reset function and set values to "0" as shown in code below:

```
<button width="500" height="500" id ="reset" class="button button1"
onclick="javascript:reset()">Reset Value</button> 

<script type="text/javascript">
   var reset= function(){
    a = 0;
    document.getElementById('Value').innerHTML = a;
    }
</script>
```

BTW you declared var count = 0 in your code (question) but not using that (apparently).

Comment: Happy to help you. Don't forget to accept as answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Some tips:**

1. You correctly stored a variable to keep track of the counter, all you needed to do in a reset function was to change the value back to 0.
2. Keep your Javascript away from your HTML. [Here's a good article](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/)
3. Your code should be properly formatted when posting on Stack Overflow.

**Here's a cleaner solution:**

HTML:

```
Value $<span id="Value">0</span> 
<button id="add">Add Value</button> 
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var a = 0;
var add = function(valueToAdd) {
    a += valueToAdd;
    document.getElementById('Value').innerHTML = a;
}

var reset = function() {
    a = 0;
    document.getElementById('Value').innerHTML = 0;
}


var addButton = document.querySelector("#add");
var resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");

addButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    add(1);
})

resetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    reset();
})
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sfh51odm/

Answer (score 0):

Do not define **a** out of function as a general variable. Every time set the current value to **a** and continue. So you can get back to zero:

```js
var counter = 0;

var add = function(valueToAdd){
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('Value').innerHTML);
  a += valueToAdd;
  document.getElementById('Value').innerHTML = a;
}

function reset(){
  document.getElementById('Value').innerHTML=0;  
  }
```

```html
Value $<span id="Value">0</span> 
    <button width="500" height="500" id = add class="button button1" onclick="javascript:add(1)">Add Value</button>

    <button width="500" height="500" id = add class="button button1" onclick="javascript:reset()">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = 0;
var displayValue = document.getElementById('Value');

var updateValue = function () {
    displayValue.innerHTML = a;
};

var add = function (valueToAdd) {
    a += valueToAdd;
    updateValue();
};

var reset = function () {
    a = 0;
    updateValue();
};
```

```html
Value $<span id="Value">0</span>
<button onclick="add(1)">Add 1</button>
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to do a page refresh (like if you press F5 on the keyboard) this will work for you.

the "location.reload();" will work also.

change '.again' to a btn name you want.

`document.querySelector('.again').addEventListener('click', function () { location.reload(); });`